# mouse and keyboard share with copy buffer via usb (or other non-network solution)

Tags: windows, linux, mouse

**What I Require**

I want to share my mouse and keyboard between my windows and my linux PC, so that I just have one mouse and keyboard between two PCs.

**What I Have Tried**

I have used synergy (a tool that shares a mouse/keyboard across two PCs via a LAN) alot, but at the moment I have a setup where I have two PCs on different networks (one secure (Windows) and then other non-secure (Linux Ubuntu 64bit)) so can't link the two networks.

I saw this: synergy-through-usb from another post somewhere. Looks exactly like what I need! However, it looks like a pain since I have to compile it on my windows and linux boxes which I am (slowly / painfully) trying to figure out in the background.

**Question**

So my question is this: - Is there an easier, pre-compiled tool (like original synergy) that does this? - Has anyone got compiled versions of synergy through usb for windows and linux 64bit? - Any alternative solutions also welcome :)

Comment: If Internet bandwidth isn't an issue, you could setup a dual-monitor on the PC and use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/) to remote-desktop into the Linux PC.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks, Interesting looking software :)  ... but, looks awful expensive, £30/month?, I would sell my mother for less then that :o

Comment: As I understand it, TeamViewer is free for personal use.

Comment: Ah, this is for using at work : (   But also, because I have to use one PC on a secure network, I doubt they would like me using this tool :p